# Passing 'filter' parameter to angular resource (DreamFactory rest api)

Tags: angularjs, rest

I am having an issue with query parameters from my AngularJS app

I am reading documents from MongoDB using DreamFactory rest api like this:

```
.service('Servant', ['$resource', function($resource) {

        // define and return $resource
        return $resource('https://mydsp.cloud.dreamfactory.com:443/rest/mongodb/tablename',
            {
                // set params to bind too
                app_name: 'myapp',
                fields: '@fields',
                limit: '@limit',
                offset: '@offset',
                filter: '@filter'
            },
            {
                // set update method to 'PUT'
                update: {
                    method: 'PUT'
                }
            }
        )
    }]);
```

This all works great when I set filter like "parameter=value" but I failed to find a way of passing more complicated filter param in JSON format as described [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in), using $in parameter etc. Does anyone know the right syntax for this?

EDIT:

just tried something like

```
filter = angular.toJson("{'parameter':{$in:['value1','value2']}}")
```

with no success...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First...drop the port from your service url.  'https' for dreamfactory specifies port 443.  No need for you to do it explicitly.  Second...You should be able to pass a SQL style filter as a string in your params.  When you set up your $resource the way you have you should be able to pass a params object to it.  No need to stringify or toJson anything.  DreamFactory should handle it.  For example...

Here is your service:

```
.service('Servant', ['$resource', function($resource) {


return $resource('https://mydsp.cloud.dreamfactory.com/rest/mongodb/tablename',

            {
                app_name: 'myapp',
                fields: '@fields',
                limit: '@limit',
                offset: '@offset',
                filter: '@filter'
            },
            {

                update: {
                    method: 'PUT'
                }
            }
}]);
```

Calling that service with a params object:

```
// the 'parameter' value in our filter string should relate to a field and/or property

    scope.paramsObj = {

         fields: '*',
         limit: 10,
         offset: 0,
         filter: 'parameter in (5,15)'

    }

// call service and handle promise returned by $resource

    Servant.get(scope.paramsObj).then(
     function(result) {
          // handle success
          // like assign to a var or something
          // here we just log it
          console.log(result)
    },
    function(error) {
         // handle error
         // probably should throw an error here
         // but we just log it here
         console.log(error);

    });
```

### EDIT

Ok.  So...it should work with SQL style filter strings.  An issue has been logged with DreamFactory.  In the mean time you can create a custom $resource action to handle the filters and tunnel your GET request through a POST.  Easier then it sounds.  See code below.

Here is the service with custom action

```
.service('Servant', ['DSP_URL', '$resource', function (DSP_URL, $resource) {


        return $resource(DSP_URL + '/rest/mongohq/Colors', {

            // params to bind to
            app_name: YOUR_APP_NAME_HERE,
            fields: '@fields',
            limit: '@limit',
            offset: '@offset'

        }, {
            // custom $resource action
            'getFiltered': {

                // set our method to post because we have to post
                // our filter object
                method: 'POST',

                // We can transform the data before the post.
                // In the circumstance we do need to stringify
                // So that's what we do here.
                transformRequest: function (data) {
                    return JSON.stringify(data);
                }
            }
        })
    }]);
```

Here is the controller:

```
.controller('MongoCtrl', ['$scope', 'Servant', function ($scope, Servant) {


        // Create a params object
        // This requests all fields.
        // And we explicitly set the method to
        // GET.  We are tunneling a GET request
        // through our POST because our filter
        // needs to be posted but we really want a GET.
        $scope.params = {
            fields: '*',
            method: 'GET'
        };


        // Call our Service with our custom $resource action
        Servant.getFiltered(

            // Send our params
            $scope.params,

            // Send our filter as post data
            {
                "filter": {
                    "color":  {
                        "$in": ["blue", "white"]
                    }
                }
            },

            // handle success
            function (data) {
                console.log(data)
            },

            // handle error
            function (error) {
                console.log(error)
            })


    }])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, but that just dont work. I tried but only sql I was able to run that way was something like "parameter='value' OR parameter='anotherValue'". When I enter "parameter in ('value','anotherValue')", dreamfactory returns 500 error. I am already discussing this with DF support.

Comment: Great, that worked :-). One last question - I had to allow "write" permission to my guest user role to get it through, is there any way to prevent users from writing data to my DB while leaving 'POST' requests available?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to prevent data being written b/c it's a POST.  As long as you don't provide a form and if you're using CORS make sure you only allow requests from the apps' domain (don't use * for production) people shouldn't be able to write anything to your DB.  So I think this works as a stop gap measure for now.  However, you'll be able to change your $resource action to a get and setup a read only role as soon as the fix comes out for this.  I'm guessing it'll be in 1.5.10.

Comment: Thats great. I can definetely wait for that fix and use this approach in the meantime. Thank you so much again for helping.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should stringify your filter data:

```
resource.update( { 
  filter: JSON.stringify( {qty:{$in:[5,15]}} ) 
});
```

Or in this way:

```
resource.get({id:123}, function() {
  resource.filter = JSON.stringify( {qty:{$in:[5,15]}} );
  resource.$update();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I am receiving the same error from dreamfactory: MongoCollection::find(): expects parameter 1 to be an array or object, string given